# Two birds in a tree

Tags: philosophy, upanishads

At the beginning of chapter 3 of the Mundaka Upanishad, "Two birds of the same kind and inseparable as friends, cling to the same tree."
What exactly do these two birds represent?

Comment: jIva and Ishwara.

Comment: You can go through the answer  (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36182/3869)

Comment: So ishwara or atman is observing jiva, but not involved in sensual experience?

Comment: Ishwara is not bound by karma, while (unrealized) jIva is.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36396/16530 two birds=Feminine mind and Masculine soul